# In using APIs with or without OAuth, which one do I choose a flow between server and client?

Tags: api, oauth, youtube-api, token

I am new to OAuth with APIs system and
my project is based on [Angular Fullstack](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack), which provides google OAuth 2.0 and [YouTube APIs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/).

**Here are my project main specs:**

1. Login / Register with Google OAuth 2.0
2. Search YouTube playlist (This is possible not logged in)
3. Take a look all video list which is sorted by date order in playlist (This is possible not logged in)
4. Check my playlist in My Page

So, which flow should I choose for these specs?
In case #1, I've known what I use for OAuth is passport-google-oauth but, I am not sure about the other things.

In case #2 and #3, I think these have to be implemented in a client flow with a public browser key.

The last case, while login OAuth, my Node will get `accessToken` and `refreshToken` via passport. And then, does this have to be used to #4? If so, first, YouTube API which provides my playlists is called by Node and then, does Node give data to client after reconstruct data which Node has had from YouTube API?

If #4 is implement in client flow to use javascript googleapis library, I do again OAuth authentication and get `accessToken` and `refreshToken` in client side? so, do `accessToken` and `refreshToken` Node have had get to be unnecessary?

I really want to make sure my wrong concepts.